How to create React-native library and integrate native android application
**My problem is I've created .aar file with react-native project and in that project one method has showToast how to call this method from another android project after import .aar file in to that.
1st project .aar file created from this project
React-native file**
constTest=()=>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    constsubscription=toastBridgeEmitter.addListener('showToast',
    msg=>{
      Toast.show(msg);
    });return()=>{
      subscription.remove();
    };
  },
  [
    
  ]);functionshowToast(msg){
    Toast.show(msg);
  }return(<Viewstyle={
    {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    }
  }><Buttontitle="Show Toast"onPress={
    ()=>showToast('React-native toast ')
  }/></View>);
};exportdefaultTest;

Native bridge function callJavaScriptFunction() used for call react-native function from java
public class MyNative {
    private ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager;
    public MyNative(ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
        this.reactInstanceManager = reactInstanceManager;
    }
    public void callJavaScriptFunction() {
        ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
        if (reactContext != null) {
            ToastBridgeModule.sendEvent("showToast", "Toast from Native Android prashant");
        }
    }
}

Create .aar Library from this code.
Imported this library into another project and below code
ReactApplicationContext is not imported I've added below library but ReactApplicationContext is not imported in android native project.
implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.0")

public class MainActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_new);

        ToastNative.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        ToastNative.showToast("ANdroid native toast");

        ReactApplicationContext reactContext = (ReactApplicationContext) getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();

// Ensure reactContext is not null
        if (reactContext != null) {
            ToastBridgeModule toastBridge = new ToastBridgeModule(reactContext);
            toastBridge.showToastFromNative("Hello from Native Android!");
        }
    }
}

I've tried to import ReactApplicationContext from above code but its not imported so suggest how to get ReactApplicationContext in android native(java) project
